# Insertion Sort program

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11

(A little background so you don't hate on me, my deepest apologies if this post is redundant or too basic for this forum) -

I am a High school student and a beginner and who's just started learning c++ recently and while I was learning arrays, I came across the insertion sort algorithm. It was pretty confusing to understand at first but after watching a couple of videos I tried making my own version of it.

The program itself is very simple: I ask the user for the array's size and then the elements. Then I want to sort the elements in ascending order but the problem is, the output isn't quite what I expect.

So when a user enters something like [4,2,1,3], instead of printing [1,2,3,4], I see [1,1,2,3]!
The program has just one function which just prints the array and adds a comma to every element except the last one. Please do not close this thread as I've searched long and couldn't find something similar and once again I'm very sorry if this is redundant.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void DisplayArray (int size, int array[]) { 
for (int k=0; k< size; k++) {
    if (k!=size-1) {
        cout << array[k] << ", ";
    }
    else {
        cout << array[k] << ".";
    }
}
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  int size;
  cin >> size;
  int array[size-1];
  for (int j=0; j< size; j++) {
    cin >> array[j];
         }


for (int i =1; i<size; i++) {
    int value = array[i];
    int m = i - 1;

    while (m >= 0){
        if (value < array[m]) {
            array [i] = array[m];
            array [m] = value;
            m = m - 1;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

}

DisplayArray(size, array);


 }
```

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to develop your debugging skills.  Add print statements or use a debugger to see how your code is functioning.

Comment: Please remove the background story -- you are right, it *is* redundant and not relevant to the question.

Comment: Hint: a major bug is the size of your variable length array (VLA), `array`, which shouldn't be there in the first place. VLA's are a C99 feature. use `std::vector<int> ar(size);` and validate your input of `size` beforehand, which should be an *unsigned* integer type. Oh what fun when someone legally enters `-1` for the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to timbre's answer (`int array[size];`), there is a problem with the following block

```
for (int i =1; i<size; i++) {
    int value = array[i];
    int m = i - 1;

    while (m >= 0){
        if (value < array[m]) {
            array [i] = array[m];
            array [m] = value;
            m = m - 1;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Line `array[i] = array[m]` overwrites `array[i]` in a wrong way. It should be `array[m + 1] = array[m]`.

That block could be a little bit improved in terms of readability;

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    int j = i;

    while (j > 0) {
        if (array[j] < array[j - 1]) {
            // swap two elements, could be done with std::swap()
            int tmp = array[j];
            array [j] = array[j - 1]; 
            array [j - 1] = tmp;
            j = j - 1;
        } else {
            // beginning of an array is sorted, stop iterate
            break;
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int array[size-1];
for (int j=0; j< size; j++) {
    cin >> array[j];
}
```

Here you declared an array with `size-1`, thus the legal index is [0, size-*2*], not [0, size-*1*].

As you are expecting an array with `size` elements, just declare as `int array[size];`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try . simple change.use  `array[size]` not use `array[size-1]` because array indexing is `array[0,1,2,3,----size-1]` for `array[size]` and

for insertion sort use `array [m+1] = array[m]` replace of `array[i]=array[m]` because when you use `array[i]`, in loop `i` fixed but `m` change. so it's dismiss insertion sort technique.

hope it is okk.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void DisplayArray (int size, int array[])
{
    for (int k=0; k< size; k++)
    {
        if (k!=size-1)
        {
            cout << array[k] << ", ";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << array[k] << ".";
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int array[size];
    for (int j=0; j< size; j++)
    {
        cin >> array[j];
    }


    for (int i =1; i<size; i++)
    {
        int value = array[i];
        int m = i - 1;

        while (m >= 0)
        {
            if (value < array[m])
            {
                array [m+1] = array[m];
                array [m] = value;
                m = m - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    DisplayArray(size, array);


}
```